# Is there a code equivalent to "Terminate drivers after each Test Case/Test Suite which is present in the Project>Settings>Execution?

Tags: headless, katalon-studio

I need to run my test using headless and non-headless. For non-headless, I want to see the actual result in the browser so I chose to turn off both the Terminate drivers after each Test Case and Terminate drivers after each Test Suite. When running headless I need to check those again so that the chromedriver.exe will be removed in the background after execution.

I need to create test cases that have a code that forces "Terminate drivers after each Test Case", instead of toggling the checkbox in the Project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DriverFactory` class to check whether the current test is executing in a headless driver, and then put it in a test listener you can execute after test case or test suite:

```
class TestListener {

    @AfterTestCase
    def afterTestcase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        if (DriverFactory.getExecutedBrowser().getName()!='HEADLESS_DRIVER'){
            WebUI.closeBrowser()
        }
    }
    @AfterTestSuite
    def afterTestSuite(TestCaseContext testCaseContext){
        if (DriverFactory.getExecutedBrowser().getName()=='CHROME_DRIVER'){
            WebUI.closeBrowser()
        }       
    }
}
```

Sometimes you have different drivers hanging from different tests. If you are looking to just kill the process that keeps hanging, use

```
String cmd = "taskkill /F chromedriver.exe"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```